# Is 0000 a valid EBCDIC signed value?

Tags: ebcdic

We have an ASCII file with numbers formatted as EBCDIC signed fields.

Sometimes the value is 0000 while I would expect 000{ or 000}.

Is 0000 a valid EBCDIC signed value within an ASCII file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer

Yes, both `'0000'` and `'000{'` denote a positive zero. `'000}'` denotes a negative zero.

## Detailed Answer

Packed decimal number are often used on IBM mainframe systems, since the processor has a set of decimal instructions. Those instructions assume that its operands follow the rules for decimal packed numbers in storage. See [IBM z/Architecture Principles of Operation, Chapter 8 "Decimal Instructions"](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/zarchitecture-principles-operation).

In summary, a decimal packed number has digits, i.e. `0x0` - `0x9`, in every nibble of every byte, except for the right nibble in the rightmost byte (rightmost nibble). The rightmost nibble holds the sign, which has preferred values `0xC` for positive, and `0xD` for negative values. The system also accepts `0xA`, `0xE`, and `0xF` as positive signs, and `0xB`as negtive sign.

### Making Packed Decimal Human Readable

If you need to make a decimal packed number human readable, you can use the `UNPK` (unpack) processor instruction. This instruction transforms each byte, except for the rightmost byte, nibble by nibble, to the corresponding EBCDIC character digit, i.e.

- `0x0` --> `'0'` (= `0xF0`)
- `0x1` --> `'1'` (= `0xF1`)
- ...
- `0x9` --> `'9'` (= `0xF9`)

The rigtmost byte is handled differently, since it contains a digit in the left nibble and the sign in the right nibble. This byte is transformed by simply exchanging the nibbles. For decimal numbers with preferred sign values, this is:

- positive values: `0xdC` --> `0xCd`
- negative values: `0xdD` --> `0xDd`

where the lowercase `d` denotes the digit nibble value, i.e. `0x0`, `0x1`, ..., `0x9`.

So, positvie values lead to:

- `0xC0`, `0xC1`, ..., `0xC9`

and negative values lead to

- `0xD0`, `0xD1`, ..., `0xD9`.

The corresponding resulting EBCDIC characters

- `'{'`, `'A'`, `'B'`, ..., `'I'` (positive values)
- `'}'`, `'J'`, `'K'`, ..., `'R'` (negative values)

To make the numbers really human readable, programs then usually overlay the left nibble of this last character with `0xF` to make it a read EBCDIC character digit. This is called *zoned decimal format*.

So far, only the preferred sign codes were used. If alternate sign codes (as noted above) would be used, all sorts of additional characters might appear. For example, variations of the number zero with alternate sign codes would show (in EBCDIC):

- positive zero: `0x0A` --> `0xA0`, which is `'µ'`
- positive zero: `0x0E` --> `0xE0`, which is `'\'`
- positive zero: `0x0F` --> `0xF0`, which is `'0'`
- negative zero: `0x0B` --> `0xB0`, which is `'^'`

## Handling Imporperly Unpacked Numbers

If the program doing the unpacking of packed decimal numbers does *not* handle the sign nibble correctly for human redability, you can:

- In EBCDIC, overlay the left nibble of the right most character byte with `0xF` to make sure it is a real EBCDIC character digit.
- In ASCII, overlay the left nibble of the right most character byte with `0x3` to make sure it is a real ASCII character digit.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! I had to look at an EBCDIC characters table while reading your explanation to make full sense of it but it is clear for me now. Indeed if not only x'C' but also x'F' (and some others) can be used to indicate a positive value then I can expect C'0000'.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Would you mind giving me a hint what was not clear without looking at an EBCDIC character table, so that I can edit my answer and improve it?

Comment: I was quite confused at the beginning because I am not very smart, getting old and stupid. And maybe also a lake of knowledge. First, I spent some time on your writing convention. I figured that x was a prefix for hexa, but C was not an obvious prefix for characters to me. Plus C is also used in EBCDIC for positive values. I am more use to C language conventions for example (0x for hexa, single quotes for characters), And even though you pretty much wrote it, x'F0' was not obviously the hexa for the letter 0 in EBCDIC to me. So taking a look at a characters table helped me understood.

Comment: Thanks! I was too much thinking of mainframe assembler notation. Changed x'nn' to 0xnn, and C'cc' to 'cc'.